# Antd Layout Component Do not Work with SSR well

Tags: antd

i started using Antd with react-starter-kit to build admin template

if i disable javascript i get this [image]

but with js enabled i get this the proper one
[image]

Also when o load the page 1st time it go fast from 1 to 2 (on js enabled)

this is the react component

```
class Layout extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node.isRequired
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      siderFold: false
    };
    this.switchSider = this.switchSider.bind(this);
  }

  switchSider() {
    this.setState({
      siderFold: !this.state.siderFold
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <AntDLayout>
          <AntDLayout.Sider
            className={s.sider}
            trigger={null}
            collapsible
            collapsed={this.state.siderFold}
          >
            <Sidebar siderFold={this.state.siderFold} />
          </AntDLayout.Sider>
          <AntDLayout className={s.layout}>
            <Header
              siderFold={this.state.siderFold}
              switchSider={this.switchSider}
            />
            <AntDLayout.Content>{this.props.children}</AntDLayout.Content>
          </AntDLayout>
        </AntDLayout>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I tried disable these styles for .ant-layout class

```
display: -webkit-box; 
display: -webkit-flex; 
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
```

and i get the result of 1st image, so i guess it has to do with flex on SSR
Any help with this?

Answer (score 2):

It would be solved by just adding `hasSider` attribute, with latest version of `antd`.

Example:

Before:

```
<AntDLayout>
    // other components.
</AntDLayout>
```

After:

```
<AntDLayout hasSider>
    // other components.
</AntDLayout>
```

See the issue about exact same stuff: https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/8604